# Gone scripts and skins while installing Magento 1.9.x on Docker

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, docker

While I installing magento, all scripts and skins are missing.[image]

If I check logs, I can see this problem:

```
[error] 6#6: *9 open() "/var/www/skin/install/default/default/favicon.ico" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.23.0.1, server: docker.test, request: "GET /skin/install/default/default/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "docker.test", referrer: "http://docker.test/index.php/install/"
```

How can I solve this issue?
I installing magento with dokcer-compose.yml (Nginx + MySQL + PHP7.2-fpm)

Comment: its permission issue.

Comment: Yes...........................

Comment: How can I solve it?

Comment: Now I solve this prible. In magento folder write "chmod -R 777 . ". This must help!